# How to bin numbers in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:
Col-1: id.
Col-2: ranges from 0 to 100.
Col-3: value.

```
id col-2        value
...
id 10.00          2 
id 10.53          2 
id 11.11         88 
id 11.76          6 
id 12.00          2 
id 12.12          2 
id 12.35        163 
id 12.50          6 
id 12.90          2 
id 13.33          5 
id 13.58        366 
id 13.64          8 
id 14.29         10 
id 14.81        725 
...
id 100  45
```

I want to make 100 bins of Col-2, and sum up values in Col-3 in that interval. How can I do that? 
For example output would be something like this:

```
id  0-1    sum-value-in-interval
id  1-2    sum-value-in-interval
id  2-3    sum-value-in-interval
...
id  10-11  4
id  11-12  94
...
id  99-100 sum-value-in-interval
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: We can use `cut` and then group by it to get the sum of value

Answer (score 6):

This is a `dplyr` based solution. Let your data be called `dat`:

`library(dplyr)`

`dat%>%mutate(quantile = ntile(col2,100))%>%group_by(quantile)%>%summarize(sumValueInInterval = sum(col3))`

Answer (score 5):

We can use `cut` to create a grouping variable, use that in `aggregate` to get the `sum` of 'col2'.

```
df1$group <- as.character(cut(df1$col2, breaks=1:100))
aggregate(col3~group+id, df1, FUN=sum)
```

---

Or this can be done with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, group:= cut(col2, breaks=1:100)
                ][,list(col3= sum(col3)) ,.(group, id)]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(id= paste0('id', rep(1:2, each=50)), 
  col2=rnorm(100, sample(100)), col3= sample(500, 100, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: *note*: my solution and akrun's are different. mine will give you an equal amount of IDs per bin but an unequal range of col2, while in his solution each bin will encompass an equal range of col2 but an unequal number of observations.